# YouTube embedded video using IFrame API can't play a perfect loop and re-buffers the video with each loop

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to make a video that autoplays and witha perfect as I use it as a background for my landing page.

I can achieve perfect looping with HTML5 `<video>` tag as it caches the video upon download.

I don't want to host the video on my server, so I switched to embedding using [YouTube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), I got everything to work correctly except that YT does not cache the video so there is a few seconds lag with every loop.

Is there any way to achieve a perfect loop playback using YouTube API without refresh?

Here's my code
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkwmJk?editors=0010)

```html
<div id="js-video"></div>
<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('js-video', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'CFgqg5B924U',
      playerVars: { 
        'rel': 0, 
        'showinfo': 0, 
        'autoplay': 1, 'loop': 1, 
        'controls': 0, 
        'playlist': 'CFgqg5B924U' 
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }

    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, instead of setting loop, set up an setInterval inside the onPlayerReady function, for example every 250 ms.. do a simple condition inside the setInterval, like:

```
if(vidplayer.getCurrentTime() > vidplayer.getDuration()-500){
//if video is 500 ms before ending, do
vidplayer.seekTo(0);
//gets back to the start of video
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Code will play a perfect loop without buffering the video everytime.

```js
  
<script>
// 1. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
 var tag = document.createElement('script');
 
 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
 
 // 2. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
 //    after the API code downloads.
 var restart_before = 500;//milisecenods
 var code_overhead=10;
 
 var player;
 var total_video_time;
 
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('video-foreground', {
   height: '100%',
   width: '100%',
   playerVars: {
   rel:0,
   autoplay: 1,
   controls: 0,
   showinfo: 0,
   autohide: 1,
   modestbranding: 1,
   vq: 'hd1080'},
   videoId: '<?php echo $youtubevideoid;?>',
   events: {
   'onReady': onPlayerReady,
   'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
  });
 }

 // 3. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
 function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
  player.mute();
  
  total_video_time = (player.getDuration()*1000)-restart_before;
  setTimeout(checkvideopos, total_video_time);
 
 }

 var done = false;
 function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
 // player.seekTo(0);
 }
    
 function checkvideopos()
 {
  // console.log("MIA\n");
  var curr_time = player.getCurrentTime();
  curr_time = curr_time * 1000;
  if(curr_time>=total_video_time)
  {
   player.seekTo(0);
   setTimeout(checkvideopos, total_video_time);
  }
  else
  {
   var new_time =  (total_video_time -  curr_time) - code_overhead;
   setTimeout(checkvideopos, new_time);
  }
 }
</script>
```